# Need help reassembling bike shifter

Tags: shimano, shifter, mechanical

I recently needed to change my shifter cable, and I ended up taking apart the entire shifter instead of doing it the easy way. I was able to change the cable, but couldn't put it back together again. Attached are photos of all the parts of the shifter. If any of you know how to reassemble this type of shifter or could link me to a guide, please do. Thank you!

Model: SL-RS36-LN, Revoshift Friction

Part 1:
[image]

Part 2:
[image]
[image]

Part 3:
[image]
[image]

Part 4:
[image]

Part 5:
[image]
[image]

Part 6:
[image]
[image]

Photos are also available on [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1F5NRdtemqMeTDBuno3uOeBJcgI5XmFbs)

Comment: Does this exploded view help you identify the correct order of assembly? https://velosiped.com/pdf/shimano_tech_docs/shifters/ev-sl-rs36-3294a.pdf

Comment: Two tools will be need to fix it easily, the big round one that normally sits on the floor, and a credit card.

Comment: @mattnz I genuinely thought the credit card was a legitimate tool (shim? flat head wrench?) until I figured out what its big round partner is supposed to be :)

Answer (score 2):

Shimano has great documentation.
https://si.shimano.com/en/manual/search?q=SL-RS36
Between the [exploded view mentioned by @superman.lopez](https://velosiped.com/pdf/shimano_tech_docs/shifters/ev-sl-rs36-3294a.pdf) and these you might be able to figure it out.

Comment: I agree with this.  A strategy I have used is to save digital copies of all the Shimano-related dealers manuals to my computer, and other documentation for future use. I refer to them often, and they are huge time savers as well as ensure that I don't over tighten some fasteners.  I can even print out a relevant page from the manuals to work with directly at the workstand.

Comment: None of those links help, I'm in the same situation. I took mine apart to flatten the spring so it would not be as strong. Did you ever figure out how to reassemble?